# Replace $n1 - $nx in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to replace a text with a lot of `$n1` - `$n5` in it.
Something like this:

```js
var str = "Text $n1 Text $n2 Text $n3 ...";

str = str.replace( /$n1/g, 'n1' );
str = str.replace( /$n2/g, 'n2' );
str = str.replace( /$n3/g, 'n3' );
str = str.replace( /$n4/g, 'n4' );
str = str.replace( /$n5/g, 'n5' );
```

But this obviously don't work.

I also tried

```js
str = str.replace( /\$n1/g, n1 );
```

but this only replaces the `$`

I was surprised that I did not found a solution with the combination of `$`, a letter and a number. Maybe it's answered somewhere already but I couldn't find it.

Comment: it "only replaces the $" because you're putting n1 back?

Comment: if you instead wrote `str = str.replace( /\$n1/g, 'something else' );` it would replace the whole thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use capture group and character class

```
\$(n[1-5])
```

[image]

```js
var str = "Text $n1 Text $n2 Text $n3 ...";

let final = str.replace(/\$(n[1-5])/g, (_, g1) => g1)

console.log(final)
```

Answer (score 0):

`$` means end of string in regular expressions, sou you need to escape it as `\$`.

the `g` modifier then replaces all occurences, i.e. $n1 -> n1.